# How can I add If ISBLANK and a Concatenate to a function in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have this code below that works fine. How do I insert a "No Info available" on any of the SELECTEDVALUE if there is no data? Currently it shows this:

[image]

I want to add a Concatenate the Employee First Name & last Name then a Carriage Return and then the SELECTEDVALUE. Can a function also do a concatenate on Columns?

```
EmployeeData = 
VAR SelectedEmpl_ID =
    SELECTEDVALUE (EMPLOYEE_TRANSCRIPT[EMPL_ID])
VAR SelectedCrseCode =
    SELECTEDVALUE (EMPLOYEE_TRANSCRIPT[CRSE_CDE])
VAR SelectedJJNbr =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( EMPLOYEE_TRANSCRIPT[EMPL_JJ_NBR] )
VAR Label =
    "Employee ID " & SelectedEmpl_ID
        & UNICHAR ( 10 ) & " Course Code: " & SelectedCrseCode
        & UNICHAR ( 10 ) & " Employee: " & SelectedJJNbr
RETURN
    Label
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to insert "No info available"

```
EmployeeData =
VAR SelectedEmpl_ID  = SELECTEDVALUE ( EMPLOYEE_TRANSCRIPT[EMPL_ID] )
VAR SelectedCrseCode = SELECTEDVALUE ( EMPLOYEE_TRANSCRIPT[CRSE_CDE] )
VAR SelectedJJNbr    = SELECTEDVALUE ( EMPLOYEE_TRANSCRIPT[EMPL_JJ_NBR] )
VAR Label =
    "Employee ID "
        & IF ( ISBLANK ( SelectedEmpl_ID ), "No info available", SelectedEmpl_ID )
        & UNICHAR ( 10 ) & " Course Code: "
        & IF ( ISBLANK ( SelectedCrseCode ), "No info available", SelectedCrseCode )
        & UNICHAR ( 10 ) & " Employee: "
        & IF ( ISBLANK ( SelectedJJNbr ), "No info available", SelectedJJNbr )
RETURN
    Label
```

Comment: Thanks so much and appreciate!

Comment: Right now when I select nothing or no filters are selected.. the Card is populated with 'Everything'... making it bad... I saw some solution that maybe to use Hasonefilter while another says something else like this. How to incorporate this below
CALCULATE ( IF ( ISFILTERED ( Table[Column] ), SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Column1] ), "" ))